# How do I store current value from input fields and add new ones?

Tags: reactjs, forms

Im learning React and are trying to make a todo-list where people can create todo-cards from two inputs. One title and one content.

This code succesfully creates one card. Now im trying to figure out how to store current values, reset both inputfields and create more cards without the exisiting beeing deleted.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I realize I need to do something about setSubmitted, also create a array or object to store my title and content-variables. Just not sure how.

```
function App() { 
  
  const [title, setInputFromTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [Submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

  function updateState(e) {
    setInputFromTitle(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  function updateContent (e) {
    setContent(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(true)
     }

return (
<div className="App">
    <Header />
      <Form updateState={updateState} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} updateContent={updateContent} content={content} title={title} />
  <section className="wrapper_cards">
      {Submitted ?
            <article>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>{content}</p>
            <button className="button_cards">Complete</button>
        </article>
         : null }
  </section>
    </div>
  );

}
```

This is the Form component:

```
const Form = ({updateState, handleSubmit, updateContent, content, title}) => {
    return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form" method="post" action="#">
            <label htmlFor="title1">Title</label>
            <input className="title1" placeholder="Add title" value={title} onChange={updateState} name="title1" rows="1" cols="20"></input>
            <label htmlFor="content1">Content</label>
            <textarea className="content1" placeholder="Add text" value={content} onChange={updateContent} name="content1" type="text" rows="6" cols="60"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" className="add">Add</button>
        </form>
        
        
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, But for only your learning.

```
function App() { 
  
  const [title, setInputFromTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  function updateState(e) {
    setInputFromTitle(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  function updateContent (e) {
    setContent(e.currentTarget.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setData([...data, {title, content}])
    setContent("");
    setInputFromTitle("");
     }

return (
<div className="App">
    <Header />
      <Form updateState={updateState} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} updateContent={updateContent} content={content} title={title} />
  <section className="wrapper_cards">
      {data.length > 0 &&
            data.map(item => {
                <article>
                  <h4>{item.title}</h4>
                  <p>{item.content}</p>
                  <button className="button_cards">Complete</button>
                </article>
             })}
  </section>
    </div>
  );

}
```